# Difference constraints on Bellman-Ford algorithm

Tags: algorithm, bellman-ford

Suppose we wanted to use Bellman-Ford to minimize max_i x_i - min_i x_i

over the variables x_1, x_2, ... x_n (total n number of variable)

subject to m constraints of the form x_i - x_j <= c_{i,j}

where c_{i,j} is a specified constant that can be negative.

How can I prove that Bellman-Ford can be used to solve this type of problem in O(n*m) time?

I have tried the following:

create a node i for every variable x_i

make a source node s

create a 0 weight edge from s to all the other nodes

not sure what to do after this... please help, thanks.

Comment: This looks like Homework. Please describe what you've tried. Bellman ford is a graph algorithm, so if you have to use it, how have you tried to turn this problem into a graph?

Comment: What is m in your complexity requirement?

Comment: m is the number of x_i - x_j <= c_{i,j} constraints

Answer (score 2):

Here is my approach, but I don't think it is O(m * n), but it might guide you in the right direction. A good thing to try is drawing a picture, suppose we have the following constraints:

[image: Set of Constraints]

The corresponding constraint graph looks like this:

[image]

Now note that in your case you have a full set of constraints, so the constraint graph will be a complete graph. We will now consider a path in the graph from your problem. Now consider a path starting at x_i, and ending at x_j. This goes through points x_i1, x_i2 ..., x_ik. So our path is { x_i, x_i1, ..., x_ik, x_j }. Because of the way inequalities are setup this path gives us a new constraint (x_i - x_i1) + (x_i1 - x_i2) + ... + (x_ik - x_j) = x_i - x_j.

Whats going on here is even though we have a constraint x_i - x_j <= c[i,j], we can find tighter constraints on x_i and x_j by taking linear combinations of other constraints, which are represented by paths in this complete graph.

So fix any vertex x_i and find its tightest constraint which is to say the shortest path to any other vertex by bellman ford. Then do this for all i, and take the minimum.

Answer (score 0):

In general case, you can't use the bellman-ford algorithm for this problem. One counterexample mentioned by [anil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/815977/anil)'s answer (on this page). in the mentioned graph in his answer, we have a negative circle (`sum of weights = -1`): `x1->x2->x3->x4->x5->x1`, so we can't use bellman-ford algorithm for this type of graph and problem.